How do you get the object metadata for an S3 Bucket object when querying from javascript
I am getting an object from an S3 bucket using the GetObject command. I want to query some user defined metadata on the object.

I can see that the metadata is included in the response headers but I don't know how to get them. They don't seem to be available on the response from s3Client.send(getObjectCommand);

Did you check the Metadata field as described in GetObjectCommand - AWS SDK for JavaScript v3?

Yes, that's empty

This turned out to be CORS needing to be set for the metadata to be returned

That's interesting! Could you possibly add an Answer with the details so that other people will know about this in future?
